# WPF Control Identification

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview

[image: Screenshot for visual identification of the wpf control]

Sorry but I am a newbie to WPF, I would really appreciate if you could help me-

- Tag 1 in pic- Which control can I use to create a menu similar to that in the picture ? The closest I came was using a gridview within a listview but that ends up using a header for the gridview. Normal listview just highlights the entire strip and doesn't look good at all.
- Tag 2 in pic // (No longer relevant, sorry)

**Edit:**

Looking for something simple like when using gridview with listview (as in pic below) there is automatically that standard window gradient & bevel effect etc. (As an idea, implementing it with buttons seems to cumbersome, first strip button border, then create all these effects.) So essentially anything already inbuilt in WPF.

[image: Image of gridview in listview]

Thanks for any help :-D !!!

Comment: Simple but messy: Buttons with a Grid for each Button. And on each button click, all grids shall get disabled/hidden except its own shall get enabled/visible.

Comment: @FirstStep Yeah, sounds too messy to me,... please have a look at the latest update I made to the question with reference to the new pic and it would be great if you had any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

`ListBox` or `ListView` are good controls to use. If it's just the 'pretty' factor you don't like, you can provide `Template`s to change the appearance. But functionally, `ListBox` and `ListView` provide the function of that menu.

When working with WPF, that should be your primary motivation when choose controls. What FUNCTIONS the way you want. You can always make it LOOK different with `Template`s, but getting the right FUNCTION is the primary goal for the control.

Comment: yeah was focused on listbox/listview only, but since that bevel/gradient look (check updated question end) is so standard I am looking/hoping for something already there to create a list like that without having to create a template myself